# Shrink a 2D-Vector in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, machine-learning, 2d-vector

I want to get into neural networks and that's why I want to write my own C++ matrix class. The problem is that I'm also pretty new to C++ and to keep things simple, I want to use a std::vector instead of an 2D-Array. At the moment my class looks something like

```
class Matrix {

private:

    std::vector<std::vector<float>> data_;

public:

    Matrix(const int& rows, const int& columns);
};
```

I know that a std::vector is a bit of overhead but I want to keep that overhead as small as possible with shrinking the vector only to the exact size needed:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const int &rows, const int &columns) {
    this->data_ = std::vector<std::vector<float>>{};
    this->data_.resize(rows);
    for (auto col : this->data_) {
        col.resize(columns);
    }

}
```

My question is: Does this shrinking work the way I intended or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks alot!

Comment: *I want to get into neural networks and that's why I want to write my own C++ matrix class.* Why not use one that already exists? (Also if I were to write one I would use a vector<T> not vector<vector<T>>, translating a 2D index to a 1D index is fairly simple math)

Comment: Because I want to understand how exactly they work. Even if my implementation will not be perfect (and it won't be :P) I want to learn how everything works.

Comment: I've already thought about using a 1 dimensional vector and translating the indices. Thank you for that tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Shrinking* means *making smaller*.  Given the context of the constructor, I think you mean *enlarging*.

Your solution is not completely ok, since your `for`-loop resizes a copy of the vectors that you wanted to resize.

Less important, but worth to be mentioned:  In addition, you make an unnecessary copy of an empty vector to initialize `data_`.  In fact, when you enter the constructor's body,  all the members are already constructed.  Finally, it's not necessary either to use `this->` to access members, unless there would be an ambiguity with a parameter name:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const int &rows, const int &columns) {
    data_.resize(rows);
    for (auto& col : data_) {   // note the & to resize the vector in the vector 
        col.resize(columns);
    }
}
```

**Addendum:**

You can also provide explicit parameters for the constructors of the members:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const int &rows, const int &columns) : data_(rows) {
    for (auto& col : data_) {
        col.resize(columns);
    }
}
```

If you like concision, you could even go for:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const int &rows, const int &columns) : data_(rows, vector<float>(columns)) {
}
```